# Error while adding 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0' library

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-library

There is an error while adding 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
Tried all ways but problem not solved.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57319391/edit) your title & question with the **actual error** you are getting as no one knows your problem. It will also be useful to know what you've tried to fix the problem.

Comment: `how to solve issue` which issue? `but problem not solved` which problem?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. please provide more details

Comment: If you have a merger manifest failed error, pls post the error

Comment: I think I got the same error, but please show us what the error is so someone can properly answer your question.

Comment: Gradle, ditch it for another build tool.  Too problematic.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got your problem, I can see that you are using a back quote (`) instead of a apostrophe (').

Solution: Edit this line:

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0`

like this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to head of you `build.gradle` file and refer to this article: [Adding google play services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)